# Google Cloud KMS java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, gradle, google-cloud-kms

I am using the java client library for KMS. The KeyManagementServiceClient.create() method [shown here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt) is throwing the above exception.

Guava dependencies look okay - 27.1-jre

```
public String encrypt(String plaintext) throws IOException {
        byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(PROJECT_ID, LOCATION_ID, KEYRING_ID, KEY_ID, plaintext.getBytes());
        return ciphertext.toString();
    }


    /**
     * Encrypts the given plaintext using the specified crypto key.
     */
    private static byte[] encrypt(
            String projectId, String locationId, String keyRingId, String cryptoKeyId, byte[] plaintext)
            throws IOException {

        // Create the KeyManagementServiceClient using try-with-resources to manage client cleanup.
        try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {

            // The resource name of the cryptoKey
            String resourceName = CryptoKeyName.format(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);

            // Encrypt the plaintext with Cloud KMS.
            EncryptResponse response = client.encrypt(resourceName, ByteString.copyFrom(plaintext));

            // Extract the ciphertext from the response.
            return response.getCiphertext().toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V

    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:629)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:637)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:567)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:742)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:737)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:593)
    at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:589)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.<init>(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:220)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:193)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:185)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.create(GrpcKeyManagementServiceStub.java:370)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.stub.KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.createStub(KeyManagementServiceStubSettings.java:333)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.<init>(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:155)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:136)
    at com.google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient.create(KeyManagementServiceClient.java:127)
    at com.project.encryption.KmsEncryption.encrypt(KmsEncryption.java:38)
    at com.project.KmsEncryption.encrypt(KmsEncryption.java:21)
```

I expect this to return the encoded string, since the command line instructions are working fine with the same project settings and configurations.

Comment: Can you share the versions of any `io.grpc` libraries you're using?

Comment: It looks like the GRPC Metadata class is trying to call `checkArgument` with parameters of type `(String, Object...)`. But that's not a valid overload for `checkArgument`. Meanwhile, the [source](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/206a2e39333e991963adc7da74cb05dd2410c1a5/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/Metadata.java#L629) makes a call that looks like `checkArguments(boolean, String, Object...)`.  Is there something in your environment that rewrites Java bytecode (e.g. the Maven shade plugin, or an obfuscator)?

Comment: @bdhess I didn't explicitly include any `io.grpc` libraries, but I see a few: 
`grpc-all:1.13.1` , `grpc-alts:1.23.0`, `grpc-api:1.23.0`, `grpc-auth:1.23.0`, `grpc-context:1.23.0`, `grpc-core:1.23.0`, `grpc-grpcln:1.23.0`, `grpc-netty:1.13.1`, `grpc-netty-shaded:1.23.0`, `grpc-okhttp:1.13.1`, `grpc-protobuf:1.23.0`, `grpc-protobuf-nana:1.13.1`, `grpc-stub:1.23.0`, `grpc-testing:1.13.1`

And I don't think anything is rewriting the Java bytecode, intellij is showing the expected target bytecode version 1.8.

Comment: </lag>, sorry

I think the version mismatch in grpc libs is your root cause. The Cloud KMS libraries are likely pulling in 1.23.0; `mvn dependency:tree` should show you what is pulling in the 1.13.1 artifacts.  Note that `grpc-all` is a mega-JAR that contains all of GRPC.

Comment: was the version mismatch suggested by @bdhess the root cause of your issue?

Answer (score -2):

Problem with a 3rd Party Library:

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;CLjava/lang/Object;)V
```

Let's try to see the guava dependencies. For me, it has been resolved by updating guava:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```